# Replacing a part of a line with bash / perl

Tags: perl, bash, replace

I'm a noob at bash need to replace the `mypassword` part of this line in a file

```
"rpc-password": mypassword
```

with `mynewpassword`

I tried

```
perl -pi -e "s,PASSWORD,${password},g" "${user_conf}"
```

but it dosen't seem to do anything :( 
I can use anything that will work inside a bash script, it dosen't have to be bash or perl.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
perl -pi -e 's/mypassword/mynewpassword/g' file
```

will work

Comment: No need to use `/g` modifier if it's just one place. This is also fragile, because it is loose. For example, `s/bar/foo/g` will not only replace `" bar"`, but also `bartender`, `rhubarb`, `bark` etc.

Comment: thats ok the password are strong passwords :) no chance of other things being changed

Comment: @king Famous last words. Can they contain regex meta characters?

Answer (score 6):

Using a loose regex without keeping backups is a *bad idea*. Especially if you intend to use dynamic replacement strings. While it may work just fine for something like `"mypassword"`, it will break if someone tries to replace with the password `"ass"` with `"butt"`:

```
"rpc-password": mypassword
```

Would become:

```
"rpc-pbuttword": butt
```

The more automation you seek, the more strict you need the regex to be, IMO.

I would anchor the replacement part to the particular configuration line that you seek:

```
s/^\s*"rpc-password":\s*\K\Q$mypassword\E\s*$/$mynewpassword/
```

No `/g` modifier, unless you intend to replace a password several times on the same line. `\K` will preserve the characters before it. Using `\s*` liberally will be a safeguard against user-edited configuration files where extra whitespace might have been added.

Also, importantly, you need to quote meta characters in the password. Otherwise a password such as `t(foo)?` Will also match a single `t`. In general, it will cause strange mismatches. This is why I added `\Q...\E` (see [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences)) to the regex, which will allow variable interpolation, but escape meta characters.

Comment: :o okay will try that to be safe :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sed for this:

```
sed -i 's/mypassword/mynewpassword/g' file
```